# data type is double, but below decimal point is calculated 0

Tags: c, visual-studio, double

**Code explain**: When I input three number, each number is saved in list[]. And then, it prints average and standard deviation.

**Problem**: standard_deviation value's below decimal point is calculated 0. I would really appreciate it if you tell me where I am wrong.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define SIZE 3

int get_average(int a[], int size);
int get_standard_deviation(int a[], int size, double average); 

int main(void) {
    int list[SIZE]; 
    int i; 
    double average, standard_deviation;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("input data:");
        scanf("%d", &list[i]); 
    }
    average = get_average(list, SIZE); 
    standard_deviation = get_standard_deviation(list, SIZE, average);

    printf("average is %lf.\n", average);  
    printf("standard deviation is %lf.\n", standard_deviation); 
     
    return 0;
}
```

```
int get_average(int a[], int size) { 
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    double result;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += a[i];
    }
    result = (double)sum / size;
    return result;
}
```

```
int get_standard_deviation(int a[], int size, double average) {    
    double result;
    int i;
    double sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += (a[i] - average) * (a[i] - average); 
    }
    result = (double)sqrt(((double)sum / size)); 
    return result; 
}
```

I tried to change the data types of variables to double type.
My expectation is that 'standard_deviation' demical point value is also calculated.

Comment: `int get_average(int a[], int size)`...

Comment: Same for `get_standard_deviation`

Comment: @Arin, Save time, enable all warnings.  `return result;` should warn about your problem.

Comment: Basically you need to make up your mind if you are going to have floating point or fixed point calculations, because right now you are mixing them wildly.

Comment: @Lundin, While integers are technically fixed-point real numbers (with zero decimals), it's very weird to call them that. /// Also, there are no fixed-point number calculations in the code. All calculations are done using floating-point numbers.

Comment: The prototype of your function returns an int, whereas you want to return a double.

Comment: @ikegami Not so weird if you work with embedded system and often has to do integer arithmetic because it is precise, good enough and your MCU doesn't even have a FPU. In which case you need to settle for a number of decimal digits corresponding to your resolution, aka fixed point arithmetic. For example `1/3` can be calculated with 4 digit resolution, which in C code becomes `10000/3` - that is 0.3333.

Comment: @Lundin, ??? I didn't say there aren't use for fixed-point arithmetic. (I used them for a decade. The nuclear plant-controlling computers I programmed didn't have floats.) I said there were not fixed-point arithmetic calculations in the OP, and it's weird to call integers (0, not 0.3333) fixed-point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

First of the firsts, you need to change return type for get_standard_deviation()
function, since now there is double to int cast, which will cause that you are getting the integer part of number.

Your function need to be like this
double get_standard_deviation(int a[], int size, double average)